# Debug assertion failed in Visual Studio but runs OK on online IDE

Tags: c++

My code runs fine when I run it on online IDEs but fails with debug assertion error when run on visual studio. The error is probably in the rand() function because when I specifically use random integer values, it works just fine. I don't understand why is it not running on VS.

The following message is being displayed:

> ```
> Debug Assertion Failed!
> Program: [Path] 
> Line: 1639
> Expression : sequence not ordered
> ```

Also I'd like to ask how to debug these errors as they are not specifying a particular code instance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>          //for rand() function
using namespace std;
void display(list <int> &lst)
{
    list <int> ::iterator p;
    for (p = lst.begin(); p != lst.end(); p++)
    {
        cout << *p << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    list <int> list1;           //empty list of zero length
    list <int> list2(5);        //empty list of size 5
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        list1.push_back(rand() % 100);
    }

    list <int> ::iterator p;

    for (p = list2.begin(); p != list2.end(); p++)
    {
        *p = (rand() % 100);
    }

    cout << "List1:  ";
    display(list1);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "List2:  ";
    display(list2);
    cout << endl << endl;

    //Add two elements at the ends of list 1
    list1.push_back(200);
    list1.push_front(100);

    //Remove an element at the front of list 2
    list2.pop_front();

    cout << "Now list1:  ";
    display(list1);
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Now list2:  ";
    display(list2);
    cout << "\n\n";

    list<int> listA, listB;
    listA = list1;
    listB = list2;

    //Merging two lists(unsorted)

    list1.merge(list2);
    cout << "Merged unsorted lists\n";
    display(list1);
    cout << "\n\n";

    //Sorting and merging
    listA.sort();
    listB.sort();
    listA.merge(listB);

    cout << "Merged sorted lists\n";
    display(listA);
    cout << "\n\n";

    //Reversing a list
    listA.reverse();
    cout << "Reversed merged list: \n";
    display(listA);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add at least the full assertion message to your question, and comment on the line where exactly it occurs. _"Also I'd like to ask how to debug these errors ..."_ You can step through your code line by line with the debugger until you get the assertion error.

Comment: I added a screenshot for the error. Please check

Comment: Screenshots aren't useful. They cannot be searched and indexed from search engines. Post the error as text please.

Comment: I added a comment in BOLD. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

`merge` requires that the lists be sorted (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge).  In your *first* call to `merge` the lists are not sorted (the lists are only sorted prior to your *second* call).

In debug mode, the Microsoft C++ standard libraries include extra runtime checks to enforce invariants such as this. The "Online IDE" likely uses GCC with libstdc++ or similar which generally does not include the same level of runtime checking that the Microsoft libraries do, and therefore does not catch the mistake.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. Is there a way to merge two unsorted lists then? I was looking for that

Comment: Depending on what behaviour you want, you should use either the `splice` or `insert` functions.

`merge` leaves the second list empty by definition. If this is the behaviour you want, then you should use `splice`. If this is not the behaviour you want then you should use `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of [list::merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/) says:

> **Exception safety**
>   If the allocators in both containers do not compare equal, if comp does not define a strict weak ordering, or if the container elements
>   are not ordered according to it, it causes **undefined behavior**.
>   Otherwise, if an exception is thrown by a comparison, the container is
>   left in a valid state (basic guarantee). Otherwise, if an exception is
>   thrown, there are no changes in the container (strong guarantee).

So depending on compiler implementation behavior can be different when merging unsorted lists. Apparently Visual Studio does extra checking in debug mode which is not required (but allowed) by C++ standard.